# React fixed-data-table: Uncaught TypeError: filteredDataList.getSize is not a function

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, fixed-data-table

I'm attempting to implement the "filter example" by Facebook, shown [here](https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/example-filter.html), with the sourcecode being [here.](https://github.com/facebook/fixed-data-table/blob/master/examples/helpers/FakeObjectDataListStore.js)

I'm getting a strange error for the state where `filteredDataList.getSize()` is called. Console in Chrome states that: `Uncaught TypeError: filteredDataList.getSize is not a function`

I've changed the input data as Facebook use an external class for it, with a Javascript map(I also tried with an array), but it seems related to the `class DataListWrapper` where `getSize` is defined?

Here's my sourcecode:

```
var FixedDataTable = require('fixed-data-table');
var React = require('react');

const {Table, Column, Cell} = FixedDataTable;

const TextCell = ({rowIndex, data, col, ...props}) => (
    <Cell {...props}>
        {data[rowIndex][col] ? data[rowIndex][col] : " "}
    </Cell>
);

class DataListWrapper {
    constructor(indexMap, data) {
        this._indexMap = indexMap;
        this._data = data;
    }

    getSize() {
        return this._indexMap.length;
    }

    getObjectAt(index) {
        return this._data.getObjectAt(
            this._indexMap[index],
        );
    }
}

class TableWithIPs extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        var testdatamap = // A map that corrosponds with the cols in the table goes here - it will render the table correctly without the filter example stuff. 


        this._dataList = testdatamap;
        this.state = {
            filteredDataList: this._dataList,
        };

        this._onFilterChange = this._onFilterChange.bind(this);
    }

    _onFilterChange(e) {
        if (!e.target.value) {
            this.setState({
                filteredDataList: this._dataList,
            });
        }

        var filterBy = e.target.value;
        var size = this._dataList.getSize();
        var filteredIndexes = [];
        for (var index = 0; index < size; index++) {
            var {hostAddr} = this._dataList.getObjectAt(index);
            if (hostAddr.indexOf(filterBy) !== -1) {
                filteredIndexes.push(index);
            }
        }

        this.setState({
            filteredDataList: new DataListWrapper(filteredIndexes, this._dataList),
        });
    }

    render() {
        var {filteredDataList} = this.state;

        if (!this.props.data) {
            return <div>Loading data, please wait..  </div>;
        }

        });

        return (
            <div>
                <input onChange={this._onFilterChange} type="text" placeholder='Search for ip. ' />
                    <Table
                           height={600}
                           width={675}
                           rowsCount={filteredDataList.getSize()} // This is where the error points to. 
                           rowHeight={80}
                           headerHeight={30}
                           {...this.props}>
                        <Column
                            header={<Cell>Host</Cell>}
                            cell={<TextCell data={filteredDataList} col="hostAddr" />}
                            fixed={true}
                            width={100}
                        />
                        <Column
                            header={<Cell>OS</Cell>}
                            cell={<TextCell data={filteredDataList} col="osType" />}
                            width={75}
                        />
                        <Column
                            header={<Cell>Version</Cell>}
                            cell={<TextCell data={filteredDataList} col="osVersion" />}
                            width={75}
                        />
                    </Table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}



export default TableWithIPs
```

I've changed a few columns out for the sake of simplicity but as started, my example works fine in populating the table without the filtering states. It's only after adding the filter example states that it started throwing this error - and it's related to the `DataListWrapper` class.

Comment: On first rendering filteredDataList takes from state and is testdatamap. Looks like your testdatamap don't have getSize() method.

Comment: So that means the data structure is wrong? It's currently a map - it should perhaps be an array then? I tried converting the map to an array. However it gives the same error, still.

Comment: I just tried debugging and it even prints the map correctly in the console, but gives this error after moving past the break point.. Seems very strange.

Comment: @cbll Did you solve it ? So far only the "FakeObjectDataListStore" data works for me in this code example.

Comment: @GunnarForsgren-Mobimation run away from fixed-data-table, they are not maintaining it anymore. I've migrated to React-table, it's responsive and many times easier to implement. https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table

Comment: I got my mind wrapped around fixed-data-table-2 for now. Solved my needs for custom rendering in table cells, such as rendering a live progress bar or really any React component that fit the table line height used.

I see react-table offers custom rendering as well. Does it cope with large data sets?  My table needs to be able to scroll in large datasets where the visible table data is only a window into the larger data. I had a problem with the material-ui Table that the load time became unbearable at over a few hundred lines of list length so I pursue other solutions.